# How to modify/update to the data before sending it to downstream

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I have a topic which has data in the format

```
{
 before: {...},
 after: {...},
 source: {...},
 op: 'u'
}
```

The data was produced by Debezium. I want to send the data to SQL Server db table, so I selected JDBC Sink Connector. I need to process the data before sending it to downstream.

Logic that needs to be applied:

1. if op = 'u' or op = 'c' or op = 'r'  // update or insert or snapshot

   select all the fields present in 'after' and perform upsert to downstream.
2. if op = 'd' // delete

   select all the fields present in 'before' + add a field IsActive=false and perform upsert to downstream.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use Kafka Streams or KSQL to "process" your records into a new topic before a consumer like the JDBC sink reads it

Comment: There is one problem with this approach. I have 10 different topics with the same schema, so i have to create 10 different Kafka Streams

Comment: Just like a consumer, Kafka Streams can subscribe to multiple topics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able do achieve this using custom transform in sink jdbc connector.
I extracted the `after` field and `op` field and applied the logic. There is no direct way to update the record i.e. there is no method to setSchema and setValue. So i have used reflection to update schema and value.

The below code snippets:

```
private final ExtractField<R> afterDelegate = new ExtractField.Value<R>();
    private final ExtractField<R> beforeDelegate = new ExtractField.Value<R>();
    private final ExtractField<R> operationDelegate = new ExtractField.Value<R>(); 

public R apply(R record) {
        R operationRecord = operationDelegate.apply(record);
        String op = String.valueOf(operationRecord.value());
        Boolean isDeletedRecord = op.equalsIgnoreCase(Operation.DELETE.getValue())? true: false;
       ...
       finalRecord = afterDelegate.apply(record);
       if(isDeletedRecord){
            addDeletedFlag(finalRecord);
        }
} 
private void addDeletedFlag(R finalRecord){
        final SchemaBuilder builder = SchemaBuilder.struct();
        builder.name(finalRecord.valueSchema().name());
        for(Field f: finalRecord.valueSchema().fields()){
            builder.field(f.name(),f.schema());
        }
        builder.field(deleteFlagName,Schema.BOOLEAN_SCHEMA).optional();
        Schema newValueSchema = builder.build();
        try{
            java.lang.reflect.Field s = finalRecord.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("valueSchema");
            s.setAccessible(true);
            s.set(finalRecord,newValueSchema);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Struct s = (Struct) finalRecord.value();
        updateValueSchema(s,finalRecord.valueSchema());
        updateValue(finalRecord.value(),true);
    }
private void updateValueSchema(Object o,Schema newSchema) {
        if(!(o instanceof Struct)){
            return;
        }
        Struct value = (Struct) o;
        try{
            java.lang.reflect.Field s = value.getClass().getDeclaredField("schema");
            s.setAccessible(true);
            s.set(value,newSchema);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void updateValue(Object o, Object newValue){
        if(!(o instanceof Struct)){
            return;
        }
        Struct value = (Struct) o;

        try{
            java.lang.reflect.Field s = value.getClass().getDeclaredField("values");
            s.setAccessible(true);
            Object[] newValueArray = ((Object[]) s.get(value)).clone();
            List<Object> newValueList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(newValueArray));
            newValueList.add(newValue);
            s.set(value, newValueList.toArray());
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is not mandatory for you to receive the complex debezium message to kafka topic, check the [Debezium's New Record State Extraction](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/configuration/event-flattening.html) SMT. You'll need to configure it in Debezium's connector configuration and if you use it with `delete.handling.mode`:`rewrite` you will get a field `__deleted`in your messages which will serve the purpose of the field `IsActive` you have indicated in your question.

The simplified format of the messages you will receive to kafka will match the format of messages that `jbdc sink connector` expects, although you might just need to apply some of [Single Message Transforms for Confluent Platform](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/overview.html) to `jdbc sink connector`'s configuration in order to filter some fields, replace some fields, etc.

As a side benefit, you'll also get much less data to kafka.

Comment: Thats a good solution but there is one limitation here as per my requirement. I want complete data in the topic i.e. both before and after. Check my solution below that worked for me